PageReference to redirect after logout in Aura components?
I've been reading this documentation on aura components: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm but my method is not doing what is suppossed to do. Please, help.
This is the controller on my Aura component, this is the method to logout from my digital experience site:
  handleSelect: function (cmp, evt, helper) {
       
        var selectedMenuItemValue = evt.getParam("value");
       
        var pageReference = {
            type: "comm__namedPage",
            attributes: {
                name: "Home"
            }
        };
        if(selectedMenuItemValue === "logout"){
            $A.get("e.force:logout").fire();
            window.location.replace(pageReference);
        }
    }

To test if it redirects properly I have to comment this line $A.get("e.force:logout").fire(); (I don't know why it's so definitive that doesn't allow anything else to happen afterwards. Any one knows how to logout and also redirect to the same home of the digital experience?), and I get redirected to a weird url, I mean the first part is correct, but it ends with [object%20Object], what's that??? 
